# Why are both of my arrays are in reverse order when I only intend to reverse one of it? [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

Trying to create a Palindrome checker of sorts and one of the processes involves reversing an array.
The user enters the number of characters to input, enters the characters one by one, and the code itself will determine if it's a Palindrome ( same words when reversed, the racecar is spelt racecar backwards ).
Problem is, I need to reverse an array to make a condition but my codes reversed both of my arrays instead. Below are the codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int no = 0, j, palin = 1;
    char in, temp;
    stack <char> s, h;
    cout << "Enter amount of characters: ";
    cin >> no;
    string kimak, rord, gah;
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        cout << "Enter word no." << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> in;
        s.push(in);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        kimak[i] = s.top();
        rord[i] = s.top();
        s.pop();
    }
    j = no - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++, j--) { // reverses array
        temp = rord[i];
        rord[i] = rord[j];
        rord[j] = temp;
    }
    cout << "Ordered No. ";
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        cout << kimak[i] << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\nReversed No. ";
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        cout << rord[i] << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        if (kimak[i] != rord[i]) {
            palin = 0;
        }
    }
    if (palin == 1) {
        cout << "Palindrome No. : YES";
    }
    if (palin == 0) {
        cout << "Palindrome No. : NO";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. `kimak[i]` and `rord[i]` is undefined, since both strings are size 0.

Comment: 1. Use `std::reverse`. 2. You are indexing beyond the end of a string.

Comment: `string r(s.rbegin(), s.rend());`

Comment: @ChrisMM somehow this works, didn't know it played a part. Set it as an answer and I'll pin it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour. `kimak[i]` and `rord[i]` is undefined, since both strings are size 0.

You can either resize the two strings prior to the loop, or use the `push_back` function of the string.